# Array does not update when using openMP in C

Tags: arrays, c, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to run a C code that is parallelized using openMP.

One of the arrays does not seem to update no matter what I do. A snippet of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
// #include <mpi.h>

#define Np 3
#define nsteps 1e5
#define PI 4*atan(1)


void fill_vector( double X[3][Np],  double x[3], int particle_number){
    //used for shared-memory OpenMP caculations
    x[0] = X[0][particle_number];
    x[1] = X[1][particle_number];
    x[2] = X[2][particle_number];
}

void update_matrix( double X[3][Np],  double x[3], int particle_number){
    //used for shared memory OpenMP calculations
    X[0][particle_number] = x[0];
    X[1][particle_number] = x[1];
    X[2][particle_number] = x[2];
}



void fill_matrices(double vth, double vA, double c2, double X_init[3][Np], double V_init[3][Np]){
    //initialise the matrices for position, velocity, momentum and kinetic energy
 
    double gL_init[Np];
    double P_init[3][Np];

    for (int i = 0; i < Np; i++){ 
        for (int j = 0; j< 3; j++){
            V_init[j][i] = 100* (( double)rand() / ( double)RAND_MAX) - (lx / 2.);

            if (j<2){
                X_init[j][i] = lx * (( double)rand() / ( double)RAND_MAX) - (lx / 2.);
            }
            else{
                X_init[j][i] = lz * (( double)rand() / ( double)RAND_MAX) - (lz/ 2.);
            }
        }
    }
}


int main(){
    //initialise position and velocity matrices
    double dt = 10;
    double X_init[3][Np];
    double V_init[3][Np];
    double P_init[3][Np];


    double omegap = 10     // ion plasma frequency
    double vA     = 20          // alfven speed
    double vth    = 30                // ion thermal speed
    double c2     = 40;

    //FILL MATRICES:
    fill_matrices( vth, vA, c2,  X_init, V_init);
    //fill_matrices_Ekin(V_init, c2, Ekin_init);
      
    //Openfile
    FILE *fout1 = NULL;
    fout1 = fopen("particle_tracer.csv", "w");

    //TIME LOOP:
     double t=0;
    for (int nt = 0; nt < nsteps; nt++){
        t+=nt*dt;
        
#pragma omp parallel for

        //PARTICLE LOOP:
        for (int particle = 0; particle < Np; particle++){
             double E[3];
             double B[3];
             double x[3]; 
             double v[3];
             
        
            fill_vector(X_init, x, particle);
            fill_vector(V_init, v, particle);
            //fill_vector_Ekin(Ekin_init, ekin, particle);
            if (nt==0){
                fprintf(fout1,"%d, %g, %g, %g, %g, %g, %g, %g\n", particle, (nt)*dt, x[0], x[1], x[2], v[0], v[1], v[2]);//, ekin);
                }
            DKD_step(x, v, E, B, t, dt, vth, c2); // Function to update speed and x. 
            update_matrix(X_init, x, particle); 
            update_matrix(V_init, v, particle); 
          
            fprintf(fout1,"%d, %g, %g, %g, %g, %g, %g, %g\n", particle, (nt+1)*dt, x[0], x[1], x[2], v[0], v[1], v[2]);//, ekin); 
        }
    }

    fclose(fout1); 


    return 0;
}
```

As you can see the v vector foes not seem to update:

[image]
Any suggestions?
You can find the full code here:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NaZEDqUz5kSriW9GStM_3Oorl2d3a09W?usp=sharing

Comment: Is it working when OpenMP is not used? Please also show `DKD_step` function..

Comment: Your problem is not related to OpenMP, in `DKD_step` function `gL` is always 1. So not surprisingly, velocity (v) is not changed. Please check the initial values or calculation.